# MATLAB code library for C++

Tags: c++, matlab

Are there any good sources containg C++ versions of MATLAB functions?  I am only looking for some basic functions i.e. fzero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fzero` is non trivial.
If your function is polynomial, try GSL http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/

Comment: Not a polynomial.  It's a very complicated algebraic function.

Answer (score 4):

Try looking at [GNU Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/).  It's a FLOSS alternative to MATLAB and has a lot of the same functionality.  Take a look at its implementation of `fzero`, keeping in mind that the code is GPL'ed.

Answer (score 1):

I do a lot of work in C++ for science and engineering applications.  One of my favorite references is Numerical Recipes [nr.com](http://nr.com).  Some of the older versions of the book included code that looked like Fortran but was written in C, for example indexes of arrays started at 1.  The latest version from 2007 (C++ only 3rd edition) corrected many of the complaints like 1 indexed arrays and confusing namespace.  Even if you don’t like the code the simple explanations of the math make the book worth buying.  Be warned some people consider the license for the code harsh but compared to Matlab it is a giant leap forward.  Other things to try is GSL and Intel Math Kernel Lib.  Good luck.

Comment: Check out chapter 9.3 of Numerical Recipes on Brent's method.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the embedded matlab subset. It allows you to convert matlab scripts into C code. I use it to make libraries out of matlab functions which I link to form C++ projects. It only supports a subset of functions, but fzero is included in the list with some limitations . . .

http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/eml/ug/bq1h2z7-9.html

This allows you to do all of your algorithmic development in the warm and cozy Matlab environment. Matlab will even build the C library. All you have to do is link to it. This is **WAY** easier than  learning a bunch of C++ numerical libraries if you're already familiar with Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it contains an fzero equivalent, but [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/faq.html) does have many C++ versions of MATLAB functions (so may do for some instances). See, for example, [this conversion table](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#syntax).